# Best practices for developing a feed aggregator / proxy?

Tags: rss, feed, google-feed-api, atom-feed, aggregators

I'm looking into writing a proxy aggregator for feeds, where a handful of users specify a feed URL and some set of conditions, and the system outputs a continually-updated RSS/Atom feed of entries that match those conditions.

Are there best practices for feed aggregators? (Or filtering feed proxies?)

For example:

- Are there certain feed elements that should or shouldn't be modified be proxies?
- How should a feed proxy/parser indicate that it's *not* passing along a pristine copy of the original feed?
- Does it make sense to delegate the work of downloading/updating to a third party aggregator platform, e.g. the [Google Feed API](http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2007/04/google-feed-api-json.html)? I presume that'll save a lot of work, vs. having to do updates, 301 handling, etc. by myself.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Do not query any feed more frequently than 30 minutes.  Use caching.

-Adam

Answer (score 1):

[Don't get bought by Ask.com](http://thenextweb.com/2008/10/21/outsourcing-to-china-and-failed-auction-killed-bloglines/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use also Yahoo Pipes, I guess...
Or this one: planetplanet.org